# ASP.net C# Text from response.write() not displayed as i want

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, css

ASP.net C# I am working with a Jquery news ticker, in which i get dynamic values from my database. I have fetched values from db into      `` `<OL> `` of newsticker list. Now, the problem is, i am unable to embed this in my webpage at the right place. i have a a div, `div id="newsticker"` in which all the data should be displayed, but the values i am retrieving from db in my `news_ticker()` class are not shown in that div. they are displayed at the top of the page.

Here is my Code,

.cs file:

```
protected void news_ticker()
{

    SqlConnection connection = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;

    cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT [job_title] FROM [job_post]");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    dt.Clear();
    da.Fill(dt);

    Response.Write("<ol id='sample' class='ticker'>");

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {

        Response.Write("<li><a href='#' class='read'>Read more</a>" + (dt.Rows[i][0]) + "</li>");

    }
    Response.Write("</ol>");


    connection.Close();

}
```

.aspx file:

```
  <div id="newsticker">

<div class="pull-left">Latest News   <img src="../images/rss1.png" alt="rss" width="15" height="15" /> |</div>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [job_title] FROM [job_post]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />    
  </div>
```

.css file:

```
    .ticker {
margin: 0;
padding: 5px;
list-style-type: none;
/*border: 1px solid #ccc;*/
color:#F9A813;
       }
      .ticker li {
    line-height:1.5;
}

.ticker-active li {
    display:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
    .read{
float: right;
   }

   .pull-left{
float:left;
/*border-right: 1px solid #000000;*/
padding:8px;
color:#FFF;
    }



     #newsticker {
position: absolute;
left: 11px;
top: 400px;
width: 700px;
height: 39px;
z-index: 16;
visibility: visible;
    }
```

P.S. please note that i have tried this code with simple dummy values in `<ol>,` and they r shown perfectly in newsticker div. But when i am using dynamic values from the db, they r not shown in the newsticker div. i am unable to figure out what i am missing? i have tried many things but now im at loss. kindly help?

P.p.s. I am not including jscript file here as it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use response.write in your case, you need to have a repeater control in ASPX like this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="JobsRepeater" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ol id='sample' class='ticker'>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><a href='#' class='read'>Read more</a> <%#Eval("job_title")%> </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ol>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then in Code behind you bind the datatable as data-source for the repeater

```
JobsRepeater.DataSource= dt;
JobsRepeater.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this not only solved my problem but also cleared my concepts.